# Using date command in UNIX to set the date and time in a particular format

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to set the date and time via command line but its not working.

Isn't this correct:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d %T' -s '2017-11-08 1:00:00'
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151547/linux-set-date-through-command-line Please check the above link. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo date +'%Y-%m-%d %T' -s '2017-11-08 01:00:00'
```

You must put the "+" sign outside the quotes and use the sudo.